# How to redirect a non-Drupal-URL to a Drupal URL?

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, drupal, virtualhost

On a domain running Drupal, I need to redirect a legacy URL, http://www.example.com/?group=example to http://www.example.com/support-request. I tried using Drupal's [Global Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module, but it doesn't seem to be working; I'm guessing because /?group=example isn't a format Drupal expects.

Is there a Drupal module to handle this kind of redirect? Or how do I handle the redirect in an Apache vhost file instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to handle this with Apache's [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) command, and certainly using [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).  The Apache [URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) is a good source of information.

Comment: Thanks! Any chance you can elaborate, given the specifics of the URLs above?

Comment: If there are specific parts of the documentation that you have questions about I would be more than happy to help out.  There's a [mod_rewrite tutorial](http://www.elated.com/articles/mod-rewrite-tutorial-for-absolute-beginners/) I was able to find that looks like it has some good examples.